# How to copy a MATLAB figure and past it in a Word document?

Tags: matlab, ms-word, copy-paste, matlab-figure, export-to-word

I have some MATLAB figures open in MATLAB. I would like to copy them to a word document without exporting and converting them to a .png or .jpg, etc.
Is there a straightforward and easy way?

Comment: I think this question is completely irrelevant to MATLAB programming. Apart from that, [Google search](http://goo.gl/qd9Ev) yields enough answers as is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to `edit`, choose `copy figure`, then `Ctrl+v` into word. It works in Windows, but not Linux. Not sure about Mac.

See [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/hgexport.html) for more information.

Answer (score 5):

Issue the [command](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/print.html#f30-443220):

```
print -dmeta
```

It will copy the current figure to the system clipboard (Microsoft Windows only). Now open MS Word, and simply hit <kbd>Ctrl+V</kbd> to paste the figure in the document.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use screen-capture short-cuts.

On Mac OS X for example, if you hold down the Control, Shift, Command (cloverleaf) and "4" (yes, number 4) keys, the mouse pointer will turn into crosshairs that can be used to draw a rectangle around the figure that you want to copy.  This places a picture of that area on the clipboard that can then be dumped into another program such as Word by using Paste.